# How to retrieve Json from stackdriver monitoring using Cloud Function HTTP Trigger with python

Tags: python, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am using Google Cloud Monitoring of Google Cloud Platform.

I have created some alert policies for objects that I monitor. When there is an alert, the notification channel will call the webhook to process.
The webhook I use is Cloud Function HTTP Trigger.

I want to get the json of alarm to use for custom send mail alarm.
I do not know how to do it yet.

Please give me some advice.
Thank

Answer (score 0):

AFAK, you need to configure your [webhook endpoint URL](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerting/notifications?) first & configuring the HTTP Auth. Once done, you can configure your [Alerting Policy](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerting/policies/create?) to send the JSON to your endpoint.

Comment: Yes. I had configure webhook endpoint URL and configure Alerting policy. How to get Json to my endpoint?

Comment: If you don't receive the notification, I suspect an issue with the Auth/token on your endpoint.   
I recommend to take a look at the `authentication` section of this documentation.   

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#webhooks